# fill null values with condtional statement using .shift()

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I want to fill null values of a column based on values in other column.

```
A   B
1   21
0   21
0   21
1   25
1   28
0   28
```

My B value increases only if A value is 1.

So I have some null values in column A like

```
A     B
1     21
0     21
NAN   21
1     25
1     28
0     28
```

I want to fill this null value with 0 beacuse corresponding value of B didn't increase.

```
df['A'] = np.where((df['A'].isnull()) & (df['B'] ==df['B'].shift()),0,df['A'])
```

This isn't giving the correct results. Where am i going wrong

Comment: What exactly is wrong with the results given? If I run your code snippet, I get the result you want

Comment: I have given some dummy data to explain my problem here. In  my real data sometimes null values are not getting updated. I was doubtful about my usage of .shift() method, if it exactly does what i want or not?

Comment: your code works, just replace `NAN` with `np.nan`  and try `np.where((df['A'].replace('NAN',np.nan).isnull()) & (df['B'] ==df['B'].shift(-1)),0,df['A'])`

Answer (score 0):

`loc` might work better here.

```
df.loc[(df['A'] == np.nan) & (df['B'] == df['B'].shift(-1)),'A'] = 0

# I havent checked if the shift needs to be -1 or 1
```

Comment: even i am confused about the shift,but I guess shift(1) is correct

Comment: shift(-1) checks with the previous row, shift(1) checks the next row@Chinni

Comment: shift(1) gives the value of previous row I guess, can you please check once @anky_91